# Connect Sharepoint 2010 (external content type) to MSSQL Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sql-server-2008-express

I can't seem to connect to my linked server database from within the external content type definition screen in Microsoft Sharepoint 2010.

When I access my Linked Server from with SQL Server Management Studio, it works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM MyLinkedServer.MyCatalog.MyDatabase.MyTable
```

returns all the records just fine.

But in Sharepoint I choose "External Content Type", i create one; On the next screen I click "External system, click here to detect external datasources .." (or something similiar).

```
- Add connect/datasource  
  * Datasourcetype: SQL server  
  * Databaseserver: MySQLServerIP\InstanceName (ex. 192.168.1.2\SQLEXPRESS)  
  * Databasename: MyLinkedServer.MyCatalog.MyDatabase (ex. AS400.COMPANY1.ERPSYS)  
  * Name (optional): <Empty>  
  * Select 'Connect using the user-id (first option)'  
- OK.
```

ERROR:

> Cannot connect to the LobSystem (external system) Cannot open database
>   "AS400.COMPANY1.ERPSYS requested by the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\me'.

I use the same user for SQL Management studio and Sharepoint. I should have permission to access the Linked Server. I've set the specific credentials for the Linked Server for MYDOMAIN\me.

I can connect directly to a SQL database (which is not on a linked server) though..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task and I found the following site very useful.
http://wyldesharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/external-content-types-reload-setting.html

You may also need to configure the permissions on the BDC Model Metadata after that, so I used
http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/05/08/access-denied-by-business-data-connectivity-solution.aspx

Let me know how you get on?
JK

Comment: As I CAN actually connect to the "normal" database (not a linked server) on the SQL server, I don't think these instructies will solve my problem. I tried though, with no result :( Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to map users on SQL Server to your AS400 users or always connect with the same user to the AS400. Check security settings on your linked server definition.